# Integral of a non-uniform convergent series

Tags: real-analysis

Hey guys so im asked to calculate this

$f_n(x)=n^2x^2e^{-(n^2x^2)}$

$g_n(x)=f_n(x)-f_{n+1}(x)$

$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g_n(x)$

$\int_{0}^{1} g(x) dx$

and

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} g_n(x) dx$.

But i have no idea where to start because i cant calculate the integral of $g_n$ specifically and im not really seeing what $g(x)$ is, i guess it is going to be $g_1$ and then the other terms as $n$ goes to infinity are going to be zero. Any advice is aprecciated, Thanks.

Comment: Your question makes no sense as stated. Please clean it up so that everything is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them can be computed using the fact that $(a_1-a_2)+(a_2-a_3)+\cdots =a_1$ if $a_n \to 0$. For example, this gives $g(x)=f_1(x)$ for $0<x<1$ since $f_n(x) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for $0<x<1$.

Comment: To see that $\int_0^{1} f_n(x)\, dx \to 0$ you can make the substitution $y=nx$.

Comment: Yes i noticed that $f_1(x)$ was going to be the only left but since it was an infinite sum i wasnt sure i could make that assumption.

Comment: You have to write down the partial sums and take limit to justify it.